# How to solve coupled multi-variable polynomials?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

The following code generates two polynomials $q_1$ and $q_2$ in complex variables p and c:

```
pp[n_] := If[n > 0, pp[n - 1]^2 + c, p];
q1 = PolynomialQuotient[pp[4] - p, pp[2] - p, p];
q2 = PolynomialRemainder[D[pp[4], p] - 1, q1, p];
```

I would like to eliminate p and generate either a single polynomial in c or complex numerical solutions to c.  `Eliminate[]` works for similar problems of lower order but never returns a result for this one.

```
Eliminate[{q1 == 0, q2 == 0}, p]
```

(* no result returned *)

If I get a solution to that problem, the next thing I need to do is generalize the "1" in the $q_2$ line to a variable t, so I can calculate c[t] where Abs[t]==1.

```
q2 = PolynomialRemainder[D[pp[4, c], p] - t, q1, p];
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE:  In the course of trying proposed solutions to this, I came upon what appears to be a bug, discussed [HERE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102724/bug-completely-wrong-results-from-nsolve)

Comment: GroebnerBasis[{q1,q2},{p,c}] gives a degree 4 polynomial in p, indicating that for each value of c, viewing c as a parameter, there are 4 solutions.  The basis also contains a degree 6 polynomial in c, limiting its values to the 6 roots of this polynomial.

Comment: @JohnMcGee  Thanks for the help.  The 4 solutions part is great news, because I suspected as much.  I didn't understand your second sentence though.

Comment: `GroebnerBasis[{q1, q2}, {c}, {p}, 
 MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder, 
 CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions]

(* Out[315]= {4096 + 12288 c^5 + 4096 c^6 - 768 t + 48 t^2 - t^3 + 
  c^3 (12288 + 256 t) + c^4 (12288 + 256 t) + 
  c^2 (8192 - 256 t - 16 t^2)} *)`

Answer (score 4):

### Part 1 - Eliminate p

I am not sure this is what you are looking for but both `Solve` and `Reduce` give solutions.

When I evaluate `q1` and `q2` I get

```
pp[n_Integer] := If[n > 0, pp[n - 1]^2 + c, p]

q1 = PolynomialQuotient[pp[4] - p, pp[2] - p, p]
(* 1 + 2 c^2 + 3 c^3 + 3 c^4 + 
 3 c^5 + c^6 + (2 c + c^2 + 2 c^3 + c^4) p + (c + 5 c^2 + 6 c^3 + 
    12 c^4 + 6 c^5) p^2 + (1 + 4 c^2 + 4 c^3) p^3 + (4 c + 3 c^2 + 
    18 c^3 + 15 c^4) p^4 + (2 c + 6 c^2) p^5 + (1 + 12 c^2 + 
    20 c^3) p^6 + 4 c p^7 + (3 c + 15 c^2) p^8 + p^9 + 6 c p^10 + p^12 *)

q2 = PolynomialRemainder[D[pp[4], p] - 1, q1, p]
(* 15 + 32 c^2 + 48 c^3 + 48 c^4 + 48 c^5 + 
 16 c^6 + (16 c + 16 c^2 + 16 c^3) p + (16 c + 48 c^2 + 80 c^3 + 
    160 c^4 + 80 c^5) p^2 + 
 32 c^2 p^3 + (16 c + 32 c^2 + 192 c^3 + 160 c^4) p^4 + 
 16 c p^5 + (96 c^2 + 160 c^3) p^6 + (16 c + 80 c^2) p^8 + 16 c p^10 *)
```

Now apply `Solve`

```
solution = 
 Solve[{1 + 2 c^2 + 3 c^3 + 3 c^4 + 3 c^5 + 
     c^6 + (2 c + c^2 + 2 c^3 + c^4) p + (c + 5 c^2 + 6 c^3 + 
        12 c^4 + 6 c^5) p^2 + (1 + 4 c^2 + 4 c^3) p^3 + (4 c + 
        3 c^2 + 18 c^3 + 15 c^4) p^4 + (2 c + 6 c^2) p^5 + (1 + 
        12 c^2 + 20 c^3) p^6 + 4 c p^7 + (3 c + 15 c^2) p^8 + p^9 + 
     6 c p^10 + p^12 == 0,
   15 + 32 c^2 + 48 c^3 + 48 c^4 + 48 c^5 + 
     16 c^6 + (16 c + 16 c^2 + 16 c^3) p + (16 c + 48 c^2 + 80 c^3 + 
        160 c^4 + 80 c^5) p^2 + 
     32 c^2 p^3 + (16 c + 32 c^2 + 192 c^3 + 160 c^4) p^4 + 
     16 c p^5 + (96 c^2 + 160 c^3) p^6 + (16 c + 80 c^2) p^8 + 
     16 c p^10 == 0}, {c, p}, Complexes];
```

There is a long list of solutions (some of which have `Root`) but I won't use up the space showing them. Here is the first:

```
solution[[1]]
(* {c -> 1/4 - I/2, p -> -(I/2)} *)
```

### Part 2 - Introduce variable t

`q2` is changed to include a variable `t` in place of the **1**.

```
q2 = PolynomialRemainder[D[pp[4], p] - t, q1, p]
(* 16 + 32 c^2 + 48 c^3 + 48 c^4 + 48 c^5 + 
 16 c^6 + (16 c + 16 c^2 + 16 c^3) p + (16 c + 48 c^2 + 80 c^3 + 
    160 c^4 + 80 c^5) p^2 + 
 32 c^2 p^3 + (16 c + 32 c^2 + 192 c^3 + 160 c^4) p^4 + 
 16 c p^5 + (96 c^2 + 160 c^3) p^6 + (16 c + 80 c^2) p^8 + 16 c p^10 -
  t *)
```

The expression handed to `Solve` is modified accordingly

```
solT = Solve[{1 + 2 c^2 + 3 c^3 + 3 c^4 + 3 c^5 + 
      c^6 + (2 c + c^2 + 2 c^3 + c^4) p + (c + 5 c^2 + 6 c^3 + 
         12 c^4 + 6 c^5) p^2 + (1 + 4 c^2 + 4 c^3) p^3 + (4 c + 
         3 c^2 + 18 c^3 + 15 c^4) p^4 + (2 c + 6 c^2) p^5 + (1 + 
         12 c^2 + 20 c^3) p^6 + 4 c p^7 + (3 c + 15 c^2) p^8 + p^9 + 
      6 c p^10 + p^12 == 0, 
    16 + 32 c^2 + 48 c^3 + 48 c^4 + 48 c^5 + 
      16 c^6 + (16 c + 16 c^2 + 16 c^3) p + (16 c + 48 c^2 + 80 c^3 + 
         160 c^4 + 80 c^5) p^2 + 
      32 c^2 p^3 + (16 c + 32 c^2 + 192 c^3 + 160 c^4) p^4 + 
      16 c p^5 + (96 c^2 + 160 c^3) p^6 + (16 c + 80 c^2) p^8 + 
      16 c p^10 == t}, {c, p}, Complexes];
```

Again there are many solutions.

I don't believe there is any hope to create a function`c[t]` for that can be used as an input to `Plot`.

The first solution was used to form a table of values that could be input to `ListPlot`.

First a table of complex numbers whose absolute value is unity is formed.

```
tList = Table[k + I Sqrt[1 - k^2], {k, -1, 1, 0.1}]
(* {-1. + 0. I, -0.9 + 0.43589 I, -0.8 + 0.6 I, -0.7 + 
  0.714143 I, -0.6 + 0.8 I, -0.5 + 0.866025 I, -0.4 + 
  0.916515 I, -0.3 + 0.953939 I, -0.2 + 0.979796 I, -0.1 + 0.994987 I,
  0. + 1. I, 0.1 + 0.994987 I, 0.2 + 0.979796 I, 0.3 + 0.953939 I, 
 0.4 + 0.916515 I, 0.5 + 0.866025 I, 0.6 + 0.8 I, 0.7 + 0.714143 I, 
 0.8 + 0.6 I, 0.9 + 0.43589 I, 1. + 0. I} *)
```

This is used as the input `t` to get a table of `c[t]`.

```
solT1 = Table[{t, N[solT[[1, 1, 2]], 30]}, {t, tList}]
(* {{-1. + 0. I, -1.93971 + 0. I}, {-0.9 + 
   0.43589 I, -1.94168 + 0.000929621 I}, {-0.8 + 0.6 I, -1.94071 - 
   0.0000163376 I}, {-0.7 + 0.714143 I, -1.94177 + 
   0.000473936 I}, {-0.6 + 0.8 I, -1.94109 + 0.000180776 I}, {-0.5 + 
   0.866025 I, -1.94149 + 0.00108421 I}, {-0.4 + 
   0.916515 I, -1.93945 - 0.000428769 I}, {-0.3 + 
   0.953939 I, -1.93898 - 0.000332329 I}, {-0.2 + 
   0.979796 I, -1.93938 + 0.000494942 I}, {-0.1 + 
   0.994987 I, -1.94207 - 0.000668456 I}, {0. + 1. I, -1.93976 + 
   0.000452186 I}, {0.1 + 0.994987 I, -1.94271 - 
   0.00109377 I}, {0.2 + 0.979796 I, -1.9416 + 0.00229018 I}, {0.3 + 
   0.953939 I, -1.93757 + 0.00229704 I}, {0.4 + 
   0.916515 I, -1.94232 + 0.00142531 I}, {0.5 + 
   0.866025 I, -1.93943 + 0.00165118 I}, {0.6 + 0.8 I, -1.94212 - 
   0.00232099 I}, {0.7 + 0.714143 I, -1.9319 + 0.000202267 I}, {0.8 + 
   0.6 I, -1.92091 + 0.00870952 I}, {0.9 + 0.43589 I, -1.93432 + 
   0.00732884 I}, {1. + 0. I, -1.92309 + 0. I}} *)
```

I don't know how your want to plot the two complex numbers (`t` vs `c[t]`).

I chose to plot the real part of `t` on the x - axis and make two plots with the imaginary part of `c[t]` on the y -axis.

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Re[solT1[[All, 1]]], Im[cList[[All, 2]]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Re[solT1[[All, 1]]], Re[solT1[[All, 2]]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh, I was trying to eliminate p and didn't think of just solving for {c,p} as a pair.  Any thoughts on the generalization part, so I can plot c[t] where Abs[t] in some reasonable time?

Comment: It also really surprised me that this returns complex roots that aren't paired with their complex conjugate.  I know that if a single-variable polynomial has real coefficients, it's complex roots will be paired with their conjugate.  Was I confused when I expected that here?

Comment: Actually, this is returning incorrect results.  I posted a [Question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102724/completely-wrong-results-from-nsolve) about it.

Comment: I think you meant replace ***1*** in `q1` with `t` rather than `q2`. I don't see a ***1*** in `q2`. I tried replacing ***1*** in `q1` with `t` and `Solve` spit out a result but I don't think there is any hope of being able to plot it.

Comment: Your posted question addresses `NSolve` rather than `Solve`. `Solve` is giving the correct answer. If you numerically evaluate them some answers appear wrong. In particular `solution[[5]`]. `{q1, q2} /. N[solution[[5]]]` is bad. It turns out that this is a matter of precision. `{q1, q2} /. N[solution[[5]], 30]` gives the correct solution.

Comment: No, I mean the 1 in the first argument of PolynomialRemainder in the code line for q2, not q1.  Read the line of code right after the line in my question about generalizing.