# NSolve behaving differently in V9, V10.3 and V10.4

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.2 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

**EDIT**
In a very fast response from Wolfram they state that this is a known problem and give an example of it working for version 10.4.1.

```
$Version
(*10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)*)

NSolve[eqn, {h, r, fc}]
(*{{h -> 6944.52 - 3662.26 I, r -> 4.68843*10^10 + 3.07219*10^12 I,   
   fc -> -1.76222*10^8 + 3.51039*10^8 I}, 
  {h -> 0.387583 + 0.0290387 I,  
   r -> 44.9117 - 8.67483 I, fc -> 415.19 + 53.0697 I}} *)
```

Two solutions are supplied suggesting numerical issues which innaiz has identified below.

The ever helpful *Daniel Lichtblau* suggests using the `"EndomorphismMatrix"` method which works well.

```
sol = NSolve[eqn, {h, r, fc}, Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"]

(*{{h -> 0.387601 + 0.0289255 I, r -> 44.9137 - 8.66856 I, fc -> 415.189 + 53.0819 I}}*)
```

One solution is found which satisfies the equations:

```
eqn /. sol

(* {{True, True, True}} *)
```

This looks like the way forward.

**Original Post**

I need to solve equations of the form

```
eqn = {0.046443987614013964` + 0.3690429826762282` I == 
   h + r/(336.458333332019` - fc), 
  0.8898053473498362` + 0.5457057083738883` I == 
   h + r/(449.9999999982421` - fc), 
  0.6745246773524501` + 0.07315743778713857` I == 
   h + r/(563.5416666644653` - fc)}
```

So I use `NSolve[]`

Using Version 9

```
NSolve[eqn, {h, r, fc}]

(* {{h -> 0.387601 + 0.0289255 I, r -> 44.9137 - 8.66856 I, 
    fc -> 415.189 + 53.0819 I}}*)
```

Using Version 10.3

```
(* {{h -> 17838.7 - 12957.1 I, r -> 2.88691*10^12 + 2.45046*10^12 I, 
    fc ->    5.21787*10^7 + 1.8054*10^8 I}, 
   {h -> 0.387583 + 0.0290387 I, r -> 44.9117 - 8.67483 I, 
    fc -> 415.19 + 53.0697 I}} *)
```

Using Version 10.4

```
(* {} *)
```

So the solution is found in Version $9$. In Version $10.3$ there are two solutions, one of which looks like it is a numerical artifact. Finally in Version $10.4$ there is no solution. So is there a bug? I can use Solve but the problem is numeric and NSolve is meant to work better than Solve for numerical cases. 
What is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: You can try one of the methods listed here: [(a/103029)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103029/4999). It might be considered a backslide, at least on this specific problem, I suppose.  See also [(a/104429)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104429/4999); indeed this might be a duplicate of [(104418)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104418/)

Comment: Yes, it is a known issue, reported [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102724/bug-wrong-results-from-nsolve-on-coupled-polynomials-workingprecision-automat/102726) and possibly elsewhere. As workaround could do `NSolve[eqn, {h, r, fc},Method->"EndomorphismMatrix"]`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try the workaround.

Comment: MMA 11.0.0 seems to have the bug fixed without `SetPrecision`. It returns `{{h -> 0.387601 + 0.0289255 I, r -> 44.9137 - 8.66856 I, fc -> 415.189 + 53.0819 I}}` as in MMA 9.

Comment: It worked fine in 10.0.2 and fails in 10.2.  So it must have been introduced in 10.1 or 10.2

Answer (score 8):

Without `SetPrecision` it actually **doesn't** work fine in *Mathematica* **10.4.1**:

```
In[2]:= NSolve[eqn, {h, r, fc}]

Out[2]= {{h -> 45112.4 + 69798. I, 
  r -> 3.6894*10^11 - 2.09612*10^12 I, 
  fc -> -3.94833*10^7 - 4.35473*10^7 I}, {h -> 0.387583 + 0.0290387 I,
   r -> 44.9117 - 8.67483 I, fc -> 415.19 + 53.0697 I}}

In[3]:= eqn /. %

Out[3]= {{False, False, False}, {False, False, False}}
```

However, in *Mathematica* **5.2** it works the same fine way as in version 9 in the subject question:

```
In[2]:=
NSolve[eqn, {h, r, fc}]

Out[2]=
{{h -> 0.3876007531699076 + 0.028925452482355368*I, 
  r -> 44.913731800940106 - 8.668559624622056*I, 
  fc -> 415.18940593411503 + 53.08192645339874*I}}

In[3]:=
eqn/.%

Out[3]=
{{True,True,True}}
```

Very sorry, this is not a reason to upgrade.

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Mathematica 5.2. That's quite a downgrade! Thanks for investigating.

Comment: Usually folks appreciate code that can easily be copied and pasted into *Mathematica*.  Leaving off the `In[]` and `Out[]` labels and putting output between comments `(*....*)` helps with this.  I left them in, because it's not that important in this case, imo. You can keep them from showing up be executing `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ExportMultipleCellsOptions -> {"IncludeCellLabels" -> False}]`.  (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Works fine in Mathematica 10.4.1

```
NSolve[SetPrecision[eqn, 16], {h, r, fc}] // Chop
(* {{h -> 0.3876007531699077 + 0.0289254524823553 I, 
  r -> 44.91373180094011 - 8.66855962462205 I, 
  fc -> 415.1894059341150 + 53.0819264533987 I}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Perhaps I should upgrade...